# Infix to Postfix expression not returning

Tags: c++, function, stack

This infix to postfix expression converter is not returning any expression, there is no error when running the code but after I input the expression it should return the string ***postfix*** but it doesn't.
Knowing that the functions: ifOprnd(), prcd(), topStack(), push(), is_emptyy() are all working perfectly

```
string
infinxToPostfix (string ex)
{
  char topsymb;
  string postfix= "";
  int i;
  char symb = ex[i];
 
  struct stack e;
  initStack (&e);
  
  for(i = 0; i<symb; i++)
  {
  while (symb != '\0')
    {
      if(ifOprnd(symb))
        postfix+= symb;
      else
      {
        while (!is_emptyy(&e) && prcd(topStack(&e),symb))
        {    
            topsymb=pop(&e);
            postfix+= topsymb;
        }
        push(&e,symb);
      }
    }
  }
  while(!is_emptyy(&e))
  {
    topsymb=pop(&e);
    postfix+= topsymb;
  }
  return postfix;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `int i;
  char symb = ex[i];` is going to do? More Precisely, what value would `i` have?

Comment: @churill it should have numerical value "0-9" or alphabet "a-z"

Comment: That's not what I meant, but to be precise: `i` is not initialized, it contains garbage data and reading from it causes undefined  behaviour. Initializing it to a sensinble value should help.

Comment: @churill I got you; but I am beginner in C++; sensible value like what?

Comment: Any  value, probably 0, since `symb` should be the first character of `ex`, right?

Comment: @churill yes `symb` is first character of `ex` but it still doesn't work with 0

Comment: Ok, next thing that comes to my mind is the for-loop. It's condition seems strange, since `symb` is a char. The `while` also seems flawed. It depends on `symb` but as far as I can see `symb` never changes inside the loop. A [mre] would probably be the best.